# Jquery .siblings() not working with custom attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i am trying to add class to all the siblings that are sharing some custom attribute over a check box element, Provided the condition checkbox is checked or not checked.

```
     if (jQuery("tr[data-tt-parent-id='" + parentIdLevel_1 + "']").find(' td:first input').siblings().is(':checked') == true) {
            jQuery('tr#' + parentIdLevel_1 + ' td:first').removeClass('intermediateCheckBoxCss').addClass('chkBoxCss');
        }
```

EDIT: This is my HTML

```
 <tbody><tr class="noParentoddRow branch expanded" data-tt-id="6" id="6">
    <td class="intermediateCheckBoxCss"><span class="indenter" style="padding-left: 0px;"><a href="#" title="Collapse">&nbsp;</a></span>
        <input type="checkbox" class="" style="display: none;" value="6" name="status[]" id="status-6">
        <label for="status-6">
            <span></span>
            Manufacturing Module</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr data-tt-parent-id="6" data-tt-id="7" id="7" class="branch collapsed" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="chkBoxCssChecked"><span class="indenter" style="padding-left: 23px;"><a href="#" title="Expand">&nbsp;</a></span>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cssParentId-6" style="display: none;" value="7" name="status[]" id="status-7" checked="checked">
        <label for="status-7">
            <span></span>
            Stock</label>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr data-tt-parent-id="6" data-tt-id="12" id="12" class="branch collapsed" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="chkBoxCssChecked"><span class="indenter" style="padding-left: 23px;"><a href="#" title="Expand">&nbsp;</a></span>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cssParentId-6" style="display: none;" value="12" name="status[]" id="status-12" checked="checked">
        <label for="status-12">
            <span></span>
            Product</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

some how its not working if i am missing some thing plz let me know, and if some thing else is required do mention it i will provide it

Comment: please put your html here

Comment: `siblings()` selects *all* the siblings. How about `.siblings(':checked')`?

Comment: @showdev: let me check

Comment: If your check boxes are in separate table cells they won't be siblings.

Comment: you are checking if all the siblings are checked, rather than finding the one which is. After you fix that, the second line still won't be limited to only the matching sibling, so I don't expect it will work as you intend.

Comment: @showdev: that didnt worked

Comment: It would be useful to have your html, I would try something along the lines of $("tr[data-tt-parent-id='" + parentIdLevel_1 + "']").find(' td:first input').siblings().attr('checked', true).length > 0

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `siblings()` selects *all* siblings. You'll need to use `each()` in order to use `is(':checked')`, because each element needs to be tested.

```
jQuery('input').eq(0).siblings().each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {jQuery(this).addClass('selected');}
});
```

However, you can also select specific siblings like so:

```
...siblings(':checked').addClass('selected');
```

OR

```
jQuery('input ~ :checked').addClass('selected')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GzUpW/

### EDIT:

Regarding the definition of siblings:
Siblings are defined as nodes at the same level and with the same parent.

So, given your example, it seems that the selector should be something like this (relative to a specific input):

```
$(this).closest('table').find('input').not(this)
```

Here's an example that makes checkboxes function like radio buttons:
http://jsfiddle.net/dYT7K/

Comment: i am interested in something like if all Siblings are checked so i will try your 1st approach

Comment: Some of the comments make this answer irrelevant. Namely @MikeW `If your check boxes are in separate table cells they won't be siblings.` Very true! You'd need to look for children of the parent table (or something similar).

Comment: what i mentined in my OP is directly related to childrens that share some thing common making them siblings

Comment: Okay, just to make sure we are on the same page: siblings are defined as nodes at the same level and *with the same parent*.

Comment: so you mean for something to  be sibling they mustbe in same TD? or they can be in multiple TR under same table or there is another criteria too that i cant understand at the moment?

Comment: Yes, siblings are on the same level (not an ancestor or descendant) and with the same parent (not a child of a different parent). So, for inputs to be siblings, they need to have the same parent `<td>` and not be a child of another element within that `<td>`.

Comment: In response to one of your previous flags, the "not an answer" flag should be used when the answer is blatantly not an answer ("thanks", "can anyone help me", etc). If it's not immediately obvious, you'll want to explain it in a custom flag instead.

Comment: @BoltClock At whom is your comment directed?

Comment: That's for you. One of your flags was declined the other day so I thought I'd leave you a note about it.